# Foreach item JSON decode in PHP?

Tags: php, json, steam, steam-web-api

I am trying to do some CS: Global Offensive inventory list for personal experience. Now I dont know how I should display all the items in the inventory.

**THE INVENTORY JSON**

```
{
    "success":true,
    "rgInventory":{
            "1847345369":{
                    "id":"1847345369",
                    "classid":"638241994",
                    "instanceid":"188530139",
                    "amount":"1","pos":1
                    },
            "1844330224":{
                    "id":"1844330224",
                    "classid":"469444104",
                    "instanceid":"0",
                    "amount":"1","pos":2
                    }
    }
}
```

So when I want the id of the first item I would have to use this

```
$item = $parsed_json->{'rgInventory'}->{'1847345369'}->id;
```

But using the itemid in the json parsing is stupid. How could I get it to list all the items' IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `foreach()` loop.

```
<?php

$items = array();

foreach($parsed_json->{'rgInventory'} as $key => $obj) {
    // $key now holds '1844330224' etc
    $items[] = $obj->id; // or re-use $key here ;-)
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array instead of objects.

```
"rgInventory":[
    { "id":"1847345369", ...}, 
    { "id":"1844330224", ...}
]
```

Then use index to get it(`[0]` and so on)

Comment: I cant change steam web api http://steamcommunity.com/id/keenjus/inventory/json/730/2